# Selenium WebDriver - Getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" while trying to get attribute value using "getAttribute"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying go get attribute value using `getAttribute` function of selenium but getting `NullPointerException`. Possible reason seems to be double quotes at beginning of attribute value.

Can anyone suggest other option ?

**Selenium Java command:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody[@role='alert']/tr[@class='error']")).getAttribute("data-suppression-reason");
```

**HTML code snippet:**

```
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="odd">
    <tr class="even">
    <tr class="error" data-suppression-reason=""Email" is empty.">
    <tr class="error" data-suppression-reason=""Email" is empty.">
    <tr class="odd">
</tbody>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace as well.

Comment: Are you sure your `driver` is initialized?

Comment: Is table visible to you on the web page? Post the entire Table HTML code

Comment: @Guy: Added stack trace.

Comment: @Rafał Laskowski: Yes. Driver is initialize.

Comment: @Girish Bellamkonda: Yes. Table is visible on User interface.

Comment: As there are two `tr` elements with class `error`, XPath matches 2 elements. please share the complete code of the class, as you using TestN. from the stack trace, it is not sure that the exception is from the line you mentioned.

Comment: Is this an alert or other pop-up?

Comment: Even stackoverflow code-highlight system says, that your HTML is not ok, as explained in answer below;

Comment: Naveen, as far as I know, in case of more than 1 elements matching one locator, webdriver's findElement will return the first it'll meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your xpath, 2 problems with your html.

1. Close your `tr` elements. It might be ok with html but xpath expects well formed xml
2. The double quotes on the attribute value will also be treated as malformed xml. Please escape them, e.g. use `&quot;` instead of `""`

Comment: Thanks ! Your suggestions helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List <WebElement> trElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@role='alert']/tr[@class='error']"));
for(WebElement tr_ele : trElement){
    sysout(tr_ele.getAttribute("data-suppression-reason"));
}
```

This should print your attribute content for each element with  class=Error Considering your xpath is proper. if not working then you need investigate on your Element xpath.

alternatively you can try below locators in above code.

```
By.xpath("//td[@class='error']")
By.Classname("error")
css = "td[class='error']"
```

hope this helps